# Global sections of $\Omega^{1} \otimes \mathcal{O} (2)$ over $\mathbb{CP}^{2}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

I am trying to find an explicit way to view global holomorphic sections of $\Omega^{1} \otimes \mathcal{O} (2)$ over $\mathbb{CP}^{2}$. I guess what I mean by "explicit" would be a formulation over an affine open $U_i \subset \mathbb{CP}^{2}$.  According to what I found in Okoneck, Schneider and Spindler, there is a 3-dimensional space of such sections, but I want this for a computation in differential geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x,y,z$ are coordinates on $P^2$ then the 3 sections of $\Omega(2)$ are given by $xdy - ydx$, $ydz-zdy$, and $zdx-xdz$.

Comment: That is elegant, and the sort of answer I wanted.  Can you give me a reference as to why this is true?

Comment: It follows from Yuhao's answer plus the Koszul complex exactness.

Comment: I think it is necessary to clarify the notations here: as $x,y,z$ are only sections of $\mathcal{O}(1)$, "d" of them doesn't make sense in the usual way, in fact, as sections of $\Omega(2)$ the above sections are $x^2d(\dfrac{y}{x})$, etc. which can be written formally as $xdy-ydx$.

Comment: If $P^2 = (V - \{0\})/C^*$ then you can think about $x$, $y$, and $z$ as about the coordinates on $V$. Then $dx$, $dy$ and $dz$ are forms on $V$. 

Comment: Between Sasha's answers and Torsten and Yuhao's explanations, I believe this makes sense to me now.  To Yuhao, as a section of $\mathcal{O}(1)$  is a linear polynomial in the homogeneous coordinates, I think that the formulation of Sasha is correct, and dx has meaning in terms of the pullback via a local section of $\mathbb{C}^3\\{(0,0,0)}\to \mathbb{P}^2$ over a coordinate neighborhood.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Euler sequence:

$0 \to \Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^n_A/A} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n_A}(-1)^{\oplus n+1} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n_A} \to 0.$

Everything can be seen explicitly from here. Tensoring the sequence with $\mathcal{O}(2)$ gives an exact sequence, which is still exact if you take global sections because every monomial of degree 2 is a multiple of a monomial of degree 1.:) So the dim you want = 9-6 =3.

Comment: The dimension I can see, but what I am looking for is explicit formulas, like Sasha's --- which is probably exactly what I need.

Comment: Well, the 3 sections Sasha write down is precisely a basis for the kernel of the map obtained by taking global sections. The wikipedia page of Euler sequence contains a description of the maps of the Euler sequence, which is precisely what you missed, I guess.

Comment: You get the kernel of the map of global sections $\mathcal O_{\mathbb
P^n_A}(1)^{\oplus n+1}\to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n_A}(2)$ by using the
exactness of the Koszul complex of the $x_0,\dots,x_n$.